# not able to insert data using ZADD(sorted set ) in redis using python

Tags: python, search, redis

I would like to insert data into sorted set in redis using python to do complex queries like on range etc.

```
import redis
redisClient = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379,db=0)

redisClient.zadd("players",1,"rishu")
```

but when  i run the the above piece of code ,i get the following error as

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

What am i doing wrong here.used this link for reference 
https://pythontic.com/database/redis/sorted%20set%20-%20add%20and%20remove%20elements

Answer (score 62, accepted):

@TheDude is almost close.

The newer version of redis from (redis-py 3.0), the method signature has changed. 
Along with ZADD, MSET and MSETNX signatures were also changed.

The old signature was:

```
data = "hello world"
score = 1 
redis.zadd("redis_key_name", data, score) # not used in redis-py > 3.0
```

The new signature is:

```
data = "hello world"
score = 1 

redis.zadd("redis_key_name", {data: score})
```

To add multiple at once:

```
data1 = "foo"
score1 = 10

data2 = "bar"
score2 = 20

redis.zadd("redis_key_name", {data1: score1, data2: score2})
```

Instead of args/kwargs, a dict is expected, with key as data and value is the ZADD score.
There are no changes in retrieving the data back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .i have follwing redis version  Redis version 3.0.503.Tried with both approaches mentioned by you .got follwing error AttributeError: module 'redis' has no attribute 'zadd'.

Comment: Can you show the full code with import and redis initialisation

Comment: Sorry my bad i was using redis  as client reference which should have been redisClient. redisClient.zadd("redis_key_name", {data: score})

Comment: Can you try
    redisClient.zadd()

Comment: Thanks a lot Nelson

Comment: For 2.x, redis.zadd("redis_key_name", score, data) is right.

Comment: Or redis.zadd("redis_key_name", data=score) is correct.

Answer (score 4):

rediscleint.execute_command('ZADD', "rishu", 1, "123").this one works ...trying  to figure how to add elements to sorted sets without using execute_command approach.

Answer (score 3):

@divyanayan awasthi answered:

> `rediscleint.execute_command('ZADD', "rishu", 1, "123")`

we can execute raw queries.

**Further explanations :**

In redis-cli

```
>>> zadd rishu nx  1 "123"
# sorted set key = rishu 
# nx = new item 
# score = 1
# member = "123"
```

Now our command in python will be

> `rediscleint.execute_command('ZADD', "rishu",'nx' 1, "123")`

In above code we added new argument into zadd command is nx (add new item).
If we want to update sorted set member then we pass 'xx' instead of nx.

in execute_command we can run same redis command separated by commas.

**See also:**

[Redis sorted set commands](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/cheatsheets/how-to-manage-sorted-sets-in-redis)

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful,
Small thing, missing a comma: `execute_command('ZADD', "rishu",'nx', 1, "123")`

Answer (score -1):

Think you are using a newer version of the redis library. From the documentation [here](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#mset-msetnx-and-zadd), it looks like the method signature changed. Think this would work:

`redisClient.zadd("players", rishu=1)`

Comment: Tried the approach shared by you ..got the follwing error TypeError: zadd() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rishu'